# Fingerprint matching algorithm in Java Card applet

Tags: matching, javacard, fingerprint

I would like to implement a fingerpring matching (one to one)  on card algorithm on my NXP Java Card. I would like to port the SourceAFIS match algorithm to the Java Card. However Java Card  supports only `boolean`, `byte` and `short` primitive types, is it even possible to implement this algorithm? What performance could I possibly achieve?

Comment: All you have to do is to implement an analogy of `FingerprintMatcher` (http://sourceforge.net/p/sourceafis/code/ci/default/tree/SourceAFIS/FingerprintMatcher.cs#l7). This will be painfully difficult without `double` - you will have to implement your own floating decimal point numbers using byte arrays.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need help porting SourceAFIS to javacard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33775547/need-help-porting-sourceafis-to-javacard)

Answer (score 2):

People sometimes ask if it's doable to implement non-existing crypto algorithms in Java Card - definitly not. However, fingerprint matching doesn't require as much computation power.

It's going to be very hard. You need to read a lot of theory, some standards and you need a Java Card background because the  language has quite some specialties. If you have all this knowledge you could do it but then probably you would not be asking on SO. So if this is your first Java Card project it might be too difficult in my opinion.

But there are commercial pure Java Card matchers (kind of post-loading options) out there so its possible.

Comment: Well, not *possible* to implement crypto... let's just say you really, really, really shouldn't :)

Comment: You are right like always :)